# Avoiding ambiguity of "more" + complex comparative

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

> As hours flew by, we kept building **more and more sophisticated** fireworks than I'd planned.

At best this is a [garden path sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence). Without the "...than I'd planned" it gets completely ambiguous and with wrong primary meaning different than intended.

Most people will read that as *increasingly sophisticated*.

My intention is to say *both greater number and higher sophistication*.

Is there a consistent recipe for neat rephrasing of this kind of sentences not to come out with "more and more [adj]" interpreted as "increasingly [adj]" but instead separating that into count and comparative, when the adjective has no '-er' comparative form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When speaking this, if I wanted the (rather rare) meaning of *more in number and more sophisticated*, I would pause after the first *more*, so if writing it I would insert a comma after the first *more*.

Comment: I'm thinking Colin - in writing, to make that distinction, I feel you can do this:  **As the night wore on we kept building more - and more sophisticated! - fireworks.**  That's kind of a pattern you see, I think.  "We kept making more money - and making it more easily!"  "There were more - and more challenging - questions every day."  Also forms like "We kept baking more - and bigger! - cakes, but we couldn't keep up with their appetite." The point is you're making an interruption to the sentence **about the word 'more' itself**.  So IMO braces, hyphens or the like work well.